# How do I get my HP M1132 printer to work?

Tags: drivers, hardware, printing

I connected my printer to the computer and Ubuntu 12.04recognized it and installed it, but when I try to print something, the printer just gives a signal as if the document had already been printed and nothing happens, and at the printing queue the job is still there as "Processing - Not Connected?" or "Stopped".

The printer is working fine on Microsoft Windows and I am sure it is connected. In the status field in the printer properties, it says:

> Processing - /usr/lib/cups/filter/hpcups failed.

I'd like someone to please teach me how to get this printer (and it's scanner) working on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I know this alternative driver works for debian lenny and ubuntu 12.04.

HP LaserJet 1022 Foomatic/foo2zjs-z1

This driver also works for HP Laserjet M1319f MFP *however* this only works for printing. The scanner will not work with this driver.

Comment: This kind of works - page gets printed, but then cups is stuck in "sending data to printer" and won't print anything unless you unplug and plug back the USB cable :(